# Allow duplicate generic types in ILMerge

Tags: f#, system.reactive, ilmerge

according to the ILMerge documentation it allows to merge assemblies with conflicting types. I'm trying to merge FSharp.Core.dll and System.Reactive.dll but I can't figure out the command line params for this.

ILMerge is complaining about the conflicting versions of `System.IObservable<T>`. How can I tell it to solve this conflict.

Thanks and regards,
  forki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the allowDup command-line option, see [this article](http://shujaatsiddiqi.blogspot.com/2009/08/ilmerge-merging-net-assemblies.html).

Comment: My problem is to specify the generic type System.IObservable<T>.